# How to run given javascript code given in the following example?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to run a javascript code but it is not running. I don't know why?
Here is the code sample:

```
Javascript:
<Script Language="text/Javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["form1"]["Injection"].value;
var y=document.forms["form1"]["limit"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Injection must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
if (y==null || y=="")
  {
  alert("Limit must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
  return true;
}
</Script>
```

---

```
HTML:

        <form  name="form1" method="post" action="/OT_Stock/addnewinjection.jsp" onsubmit="return validateForm()"> 

        <input type="text" name="Injection" maxlength="100" size="20" value="" style="textfield">
         <input type="text" name="limit" maxlength="100" size="20" value="" style="textfield" >



        <input type="submit"  value="Add Name" class="buttonmain">
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove the `onclick` from the button
2. Add `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` to the form element.

The crucial bit is the `return` keyword. Without it the form will always submit. With it, when the `validateForm` method returns false (invalid form) the form will not submit.

---

**Edit**: OP has updated his question with the above suggestions.

Comment: I made all changes still its not working. Why Please tell me??

Comment: @Samiksha - works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/pRVP5/ - check other javascript is not erroring on your page. If you want further help define "not working".

Comment: There is no other javascript on my page. Not working means even though I click submit with blank fields the page is not returning.

Comment: @Samiksha - What do you mean "the page is not returning"? Returning what? If you click submit with blank fields a javascript alert should popup and the page not submit... thats what your code implies you're trying to achieve!

Comment: Ya that's right but page is submitting to the page specified even though i am submitting with blank fields. Don't know why?

Comment: @Samiksha - Check my jsfiddle link above, does that work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

forma name is " form1", instead of it should be "form1".
Don't use language in the script tag instead use `type='text/javascript'`.